# What is the SQL Server equivalent of pg_typeof(), how can I get the type of a column returned in a result set?

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, metadata

Using PostgreSQL, I can use [`pg_typeof(exp)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-info.html) like

```
SELECT pg_typeof( cast(1 AS int) );
SELECT pg_typeof(x), x FROM foo;
```

And get back the result (`integer` in the case of the first example). Is there a SQL Server equivalent? How can I find the result given a field in a result set?

```
SELECT x
FROM foo;
```

I want to know what type `x` is?

Answer (score 1):

There are various indirect methods, but nothing quite as simple as `pg_typeof`.

[`SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql) is often used for convenience, but has limitations since it cannot contain all other types.

Writing the subject of inquiry to a table then inspecting metadata is one method. Convenience system stored procedures like [`sys.sp_help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-transact-sql) can be employed as a somewhat more convenient method than writing a query against the metadata views.

Another, conceptually-related idea is to call:

- [`sys.sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) (procedure); or
- [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) (function)

For example:

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_describe_first_result_set
    @tsql = N'SELECT 1.0;'

SELECT FRS.* 
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
    (N'SELECT 1.0;', DEFAULT, DEFAULT) AS FRS;
```

These return a great deal of internal information, including type details. The above example returns:

| system_type_name |
| --- |
| numeric(2,1) |

An alias type example:

```
CREATE TYPE Banana FROM binary(456) NOT NULL;

EXECUTE sys.sp_describe_first_result_set
    @tsql = N'DECLARE @b Banana; SELECT @b;'

SELECT 
    FRS.system_type_id,
    FRS.system_type_name,
    FRS.user_type_id,
    FRS.user_type_schema,
    FRS.user_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
    (N'DECLARE @b Banana; SELECT @b;', DEFAULT, DEFAULT) AS FRS;
```

returns (in part):

| system_type_id | system_type_name | user_type_id | user_type_schema | user_type_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 173 | binary(456) | 260 | dbo | Banana |

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use [`SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY( expression , property )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), where `property` is `"BaseType"`.

```
-- returns int
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(cast(42 as int), 'BaseType');
```

It's also **totally** broken on `NULL`,

```
-- returns null
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(cast(null AS int), 'BaseType');=
```

And it does not work on all types, on unsupported types it panics.

> ```
> Msg 206 Level 16 State 2 Line 1
> Operand type clash: timestamp is incompatible with sql_variant
> ```

And I can't seem to find any useful information with it if the type is a [user-defined type](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/291397/2639) (as compared to a system base type) it returns the base type.