# How can I cast to a user-defined type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, sql-server-2019, user-defined-type

SQL Server provides an ability to create a user defined type with [`CREATE TYPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-user-defined-data-type-alias?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
CREATE TYPE foo FROM int NOT NULL ;
```

However, there is no mention how I construct a value with that type. Is this of use anywhere outside of `CREATE TABLE`? I'm not having luck with `CAST` or `CONVERT`?

```
SELECT cast(1 AS foo);
```

> ```
> Msg 243 Level 16 State 2 Line 1
> Type foo is not a defined system type.
> ```

I can see these types exist independently of their basetypes

```
SELECT TYPE_NAME(TYPE_ID(N'foo'));
```

And they maintain that independence when put on a table,

```
CREATE TABLE bar ( a foo );
-- will list it as `foo` and not `int`
exec sp_help 'bar'
```

Answer (score 4):

[CLR user-defined types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/clr-user-defined-types) can be used with `CAST` and `CONVERT` as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql).

From example 'I' there:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY mytest FROM 'c:\test.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
CREATE TYPE Point EXTERNAL NAME mytest.Point;
GO  
DECLARE @p Point = CONVERT(Point, '');
SET @p.SetXY(22, 23);
```

You can find more examples and usage information in the documentation at [Working with User-Defined Types - Manipulating UDT Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/working-with-user-defined-types-manipulating-udt-data), e.g.

```
UPDATE dbo.Points  
SET PointValue.SetXY(5, 99)  
WHERE ID = 3;
```

[Alias data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addtype-transact-sql) are a deprecated and much older implementation. They are literally aliases for existing base types, perhaps with restrictions and a default bound to them (also deprecated features).

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from the [CAST documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) with my emphasis added:

> data_type The target data type. This includes xml, bigint, and
> sql_variant. ***Alias data types cannot be used.***

In addition to table DDL, user-defined alias types can be used as local variables:

```
DECLARE @v foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Dan said, you can also use **user-defined types** (especially **user-defined table types**) as parameters of a **stored procedure** or **function**, as a way to pass more complex objects from the consumer to that **stored procedure** / **function**. This makes it a helpful alternative to passing in a comma-delimited value list in a `VARCHAR`, or series of `VARCHAR` parameters, for example. So there are a few use-cases for **user-defined types**.